# Can you view historic logs for parse.com cloud code?

Tags: parse-platform

On the Parse.com cloud-code console, I can see logs, but they only go back maybe 100-200 lines. Is there a way to see or download older logs?

I've searched their website & googled, and don't see anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the `parse` command-line tool, you can retrieve an arbitrary number of log lines:

```
Usage: 
  parse logs [flags]

Aliases:
  logs, log

Flags:
  -f, --follow=false: Emulates tail -f and streams new messages from the server
  -l, --level="INFO": The log level to restrict to. Can be 'INFO' or 'ERROR'.
  -n, --num=10: The number of the messages to display
```

Not sure if there is a limit, but I've been able to fetch 5000 lines of log with this command:

```
parse logs prod -n 5000
```

Answer (score 4):

To add on to Pascal Bourque's answer, you may also wish to filter the logs by a given range of dates. To achieve this, I used the following:

```
parse logs -n 5000 | sed -n '/2016-01-10/, /2016-01-15/p' > filteredLog.txt
```

This will get up to 5000 logs, use the `sed` command to keep all of the logs which are between `2016-01-10` and `2016-01-15`, and store the results in filteredLog.txt.